# Gmail authentication in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-oauth

I want to do Gmail authentication with access token. I am passing values like ,

```
const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    uri: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
    qs: {
        access_token: req.body.gmailToken,
        fields: 'id,name,first_name,last_name,email,picture'
    }
};
```

But I am not able to get auth data from gmail.

Is there another way to get auth data from Gmail Only by passing accessToken?

Comment: Please include some more details. Where is that gmailToken coming from? Also why are you accessing Google Plus instead of gmail?

Comment: req.body.gmailToken from request. And I don't have any idea what to pass in uri. I have made same authentication like this for facebook.

Comment: still pretty unclear to me. Google has a very detailed documentation for this. Since "from request" could be almost anything, I won't bother asking for more details I'm afraid of getting another too vague answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> uri: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',

Is the end point for the Google+ api no the gmail api.  Gmail endpoint looks like this

> https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/

The following tutorial mail help [Node.js Quickstart - Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs)

Gmail Authentication

```
/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 *
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
  var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
  var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
  var auth = new googleAuth();
  var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function(err, token) {
    if (err) {
      getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
    } else {
      oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: well you might want to try with the correct url that was just an example there is a lot of urls actually one for each method you are trying to access you may want to consult the documentation https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/  Using a Google+ endpoint is not going to result in Gmail data.   You need to find the correct gmail end point for the method you are trying to access.

Answer (score 1):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=token
```

This works for me. From that can get user information.

Answer (score 0):

Try With:

For gmail authentication

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me?token=access_token